ReCAPTCHA token is null on server side for invisible reCAPTCHA version 2
I'm trying to add the recaptcha invisible version 2 to the Sitecore form.
I created the invisible recaptcha custom form element with the custom recaptcha validation
I follow this article to add a new field Form Submit Script in Sitecore and update the view file for submit button \Views\FormBuilder\FieldTemplates\Button.cshtml
In the Sitecore field "Form Submit Script", I call grecaptcha.execute();
In the view file for the recaptcha custom form element, I have a data-callback method to assign the recaptcha token to the hidden field
function onSubmit(token) {
   document.getElementById("@Html.IdFor(m => Model.Value)").value = token;
}

Since this is the invisible recaptcha, I must bind the challenge to the submit button.
The issue is when the user submits the form, while the recaptcha generates the token and has not assigned that token to the hidden field yet, the form has already been submitted, so when it comes to the recaptcha validation the token is null.
How to fix this issue? or is there any better way to add the recaptcha invisible version 2 to Sitecore form?

As what I understand V2 will show an Invisible reCAPTCHA badge. V3 is invisible without any user interaction.

When you are using version 2 of google recaptcha, you can add invisible captcha and hidden element to send g-recaptcha response to server as below.
<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="site_key" data-size="invisible" data-callback="onSubmit"></div>
<input type="hidden" class="g-recaptcha-hidden" />

Inside the javascript, call grecaptcha.execute to programatically trigger recaptcha as below.
var currentForm;
function onSubmit(token) {
    document.querySelector(".g-recaptcha-hidden").value = token;
    currentForm.submit();
}

var formSbtElement = document.querySelector("form input[type='submit']");
if(formSbtElement){
  formSbtElement.addEventListener("click",function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    grecaptcha.execute();
    currentForm = event.currentTarget.closest('form');
  });
}

document.querySelector("form").setAttribute("action", window.location.pathname);

if ( window.history.replaceState ) {
  window.history.replaceState( null, null, window.location.href );
}

In the above function, token retrieved from the callback(onSubmit) is set in the hidden field and sent along on the form submission. This token then can be retrieved at backend for further verification.
Token will be sent in the request payload as below:

In case the form submission gives error, you can add input type hidden element before form submission as below, on the callback function.
function onSubmit(token) {
   document.querySelector(".g-recaptcha-hidden").value = token;
   var input = document.createElement("input");
   input.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
   input.setAttribute("value", "Submit");
   input.setAttribute("name", 
   currentForm.querySelector("input[type='submit']").name);
   currentForm.insertBefore(input,currentForm.firstChild);
   currentForm.submit();
}

Note: We need to add input type hidden element on the above script since inside the BaseFormBuilderController there is a check for navigation data. If navigation data is null, it sends a Bad request error.
Navigation data is created from NavigationDataModelBinder class. Inside this class, it checks for navigation button length should be greater than one else it sets to null. Hence one more submit button is added though the script as the first child in order to prevent this issue.

Navigation buttons are read from the payload as below. The value of the NavigationButtons field is read which is then used to calculate other two navigation buttons.

Let me know in case you face any issues. Hope this helps!!!

Hi @ckhanna, I tried that, but i get token is null.
on https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/v3, I see similar example for recaptcha v2. I'm using recaptcha invisible version 2. Does you code work with recaptcha invisible version 2?

@mv98 I modified the above answer to work with recaptcha version 2 as well. Hope this helps!!!

@chhanna, thanks for your reply, I will try this. just to be clear, this is for Sitecore form, right?

yes @mv98 this is for Sitecore form..Let me know in case you face any issues.

hi @ckhanna, I tried that. I can see it generates the token and assign it to the hidden field. but after submitting the form, it goes to this url /formbuilder?sc_site=chrobinson-en-us&fxb.FormItemId=2c7c9f9e-f420-4639-b297-bb1dd30096ba&fxb.HtmlPrefix=fxb.d57c0020-5637-46f6-b8f7-d62f84629bb8 and get 400 error (Bad request)

@mv98 I also got the bad request error. Did you modifed the onsubmit handler with the addition of hidden field as above.This hidden field with value 'Submit' should also be sent on form submission otherwise we get this error.

hi @ckhanna, I did tried that, but still the same bad request error

@mv98 The hidden element should be added as a first child. I have modified the above script to work with form layout as well. Let me know in case you still face any issue.

Hi @ckhanna, it work! Thanks for your help. I have a question. why do we need that hidden element (input.setAttribute("value", "Submit");) and why we need to add it as a first child

@mv98 Glad to hear it worked for you. This hidden field is required since if you check the formbuilder controller inside Sitecore.ExperienceForms.Mvc.dll, it looks for element type as submit as a first navigation button, otherwise it returns Bad Request error. Hope this answers your query.

hi @ckhanna, did you mean looks for element type as hidden (since we add a hidden field)? For the form that does not have recaptcha, we don't have this field but why it still works?  I open Sitecore.ExperienceForms.Mvc.dll now, I'm on namespace Sitecore.ExperienceForms.Mvc.Controllers and public class FormBuilderController : BaseFormBuilderController, but could not find it. Can you show me where? Thanks ckhanna, just try to understand this

@mv98 the logic for this resides inside the BaseFormBuilderController class, there you can search for 'BadRequest'. When the navigation data is null, we get BadRequest error. This navigation data is constructed from NavigationDataModelBinder class inside which logic for returning navigation data is set inside CreateNavigationData function. This function returns null if the navigation button submit is less than or equal to one. Hence this change is needed, hope this explains the reason for this change.

hi @ckhanna, when we add this code
var input = document.createElement("input");
input.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
input.setAttribute("value", "Submit");
input.setAttribute("name",
currentForm.querySelector("input[type='submit']").name);
currentForm.insertBefore(input, currentForm.firstChild);
it will generate this 
why this element is counted as navigation button submit

@mv98 I have updated the response for navigation buttons to explain what is happening behind the scenes. Hope that clears you!!!

Hi @ckhanna, I found an issue today. so when i submit the form and recaptcha think I'm a human then everything is working. It generates the token and send it to google to verify. But if recaptcha think I'm a bot then it prompts me to solve the captcha. After I solve the captcha, I get this error "The provided anti-forgery token was meant for a different claims-based user than the current user"

@mv98 are you getting this issue on local? This does not seems to be related to recaptcha. Can you check if the antiforgery token is getting changed..I am not getting this issue even when I solve the captcha and submit.

hi @ckhanna, yes i'm getting this issue on local

hi @ckhanna, by the way, since we use invisible recaptcha, so it prompt the recaptcha randomly. Is there any way to make it prompt the captcha so we can test it?

@mv98 no I am not aware if there is any way to prompt the captcha forcefully while using invisible captcha. It is random as you said...You might turn on the console window. It may help to bring the captcha. Between is there any reason you are not using v3 since returns a score for each request without user friction.

hi @ckhanna, so did you test it in local and after you solve the captcha, it still working for you?
did you use @Html.AntiForgeryToken()?

ya @mv98 i just tested again with solving captcha it works fine..@Html.AntiForgeryToken() is there inside my form view. Are you using the exactly same approach which I mentioned above..Can you check if form is getting submitted twice by any chance.

hi @ckhanna, I just tested it and solved the captcha and it works now

@mv98 Glad it works for you now. Can you please accept the answer as well. Thanks for the same!!!
